# way to create an object with many relations, some optional, some not in Prisma and tRPC

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma, trpc

I'm trying to create a route to create a object called "Market". Each market has many relations which must either be created or connected when the market is created. Some of these relations are optional and when the API route is called, the data to create the market might be partial. What is the best way I can go with doing this?

This is the Prisma Market Schema:

```js
model Market {
  id              String            @id @default(cuid())
  code            String            @db.VarChar(4)
  ownerId         String
  banner          MarketBanner?     @relation(fields: [bannerId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  bannerId        String?           @unique
  name            String            @db.VarChar(150)
  name_th         String            @db.VarChar(150)
  telephone       String?           @db.VarChar(20)
  homeTel         String?           @db.VarChar(20)
  email           String?           @db.VarChar(100)
  description     String            @db.VarChar(255)
  description_th  String            @db.VarChar(255)
  briefHistory    String            @db.VarChar(255)
  briefHistory_th String            @db.VarChar(255)
  microMap        MicroMap?         @relation(fields: [microMapId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  microMapId      String?           @unique
  uniqueServices  UniqueService[]
  openingHours    BusinessHour[]
  nearbyLocations NearbyLocations[]
  tags            Tag[]
  vendors         Vendor[]
  averageRatings  Float             @default(0.0)
  ratings         Int               @default(0)
  reviews         MarketReview[]
  latitude        Float             @default(0.0)
  longitude       Float             @default(0.0)
  taxId           String?           @db.VarChar(20)
  isVerified      Boolean           @default(false)
  status          Status            @default(ACTIVE)
  createAt        DateTime          @default(now())
  updateAt        DateTime          @updatedAt

  @@unique([id])
  @@index([ownerId])
}
```

This is what my current tRPC route for creating a market looks like. It is currently incomplete as I'm not sure if this is the correct way or not.

```js
import { publicProcedure, router } from "../trpc";
import { z } from "zod";
import db from "@/app/(prisma)/prisma";
import MarketSchema from "../schemas/MarketSchema";

export const marketRouter = router({
  all: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
    const markets = await db.market.findMany({});
    return markets;
  }),

  get: publicProcedure
    .input(z.object({ marketId: z.string() }))
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const market = await db.market.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: input.marketId,
        },
      });
      return market;
    }),

  create: publicProcedure.input(MarketSchema).mutation(async ({ input }) => {
    const {
      banner,
      microMap,
      uniqueServices,
      openingHours,
      nearbyLocations,
      tags,
      ...rest
    } = input;

    const marketResult = await db.market.create({
      data: {
        ...rest,
      },
    });

    const bannerResult = banner
      ? await db.marketBanner.create({
          data: {
            image: banner.image,
          },
          where: {
            id: marketResult.id,
          },
        })
      : null;

    const microMapResult = microMap
      ? await db.microMap.create({
          data: {
            image: microMap.image,
          },
          where: {
            id: marketResult.id,
          },
        })
      : null;

    const uniqueServicesResult = uniqueServices
      ? await db.uniqueService.createMany({
          data: uniqueServices,
        })
      : null;

    const openingHoursResult = openingHours
      ? await db.businessHour.createMany({
          data: openingHours,
        })
      : null;

    const nearbyLocationsResult = nearbyLocations
      ? await db.nearbyLocation.createMany({
          data: nearbyLocations,
        })
      : null;
  }),
});
```

What I expect is to be able to create a market, with or without the optional fields/relations. Next, I'm wondering the same for updating the information.